# Let $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a monotone function, and suppose that $T(x)=\frac{f(x)+1-f(1-x)}{2}$. Can we find $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a monotone and continuous function, and suppose that $\forall x\in[0,1]:T(x)=\frac{f(x)+1-f(1-x)}{2}$.

- Is there a unique monotone and continuous function $f$ that satisfies the above?
- Can we express $f(x)$ explicitly (as a function of $T$)?

---

For example, if $T(x)=ax+\frac{1-a}{2}$ for some $a>0$, then $f(x)=T(x)-T(0)=ax$ works.

---

As @Clement answered, if $f$ satisfies the condition, then so will $f+c$ for some constant $c$.

> Is $f$ unique up to an additive constant?

Comment: Note that for any function $g(x)$, taking $f(x) = g(x) + g(1-x)$ leads to $T(x) = 0$.

Comment: We could frame this equivalently as follows: if $T:[-1/2,1/2] \to [0,1]$ is monotone and continuous with $T(x) = \frac 12(1 + f(x) - f(-x))$, then is there a unique $f$ corresponding to this $T$? I strongly suspect that this is not the case since $T$ depends only on the **odd part** of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not unique, as for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that if $f(x) = x + a$ then $T(x) = x$.

It is not unique up to additive constant either. The idea is that if $f(x) = f(1 - x)$, then $T(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ necessarily. For instance, consider:
$$
f(x) = ax^n + a(1 - x)^n
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for any of such $a,n$, we have that $T(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

**EDIT**: There also exists $T$ such that no such $f$ exists. One example is the case where $T(x) = 0$. Then this reduces to the problem of solving for:
$$
f(1 - x) = f(x) + 1
$$
But letting $x = 0$ gives $f(1) = f(0) + 1$, and letting $x = 1$ gives $f(1) = f(0) - 1$, a contradiction. This probably suggests that $f$ cannot be expressed in terms of $T$.

Comment: Good point. And is $f$ unique up to an additive constant?

Comment: @MA Also no, because any constant function $f$ will also work (unless you require *strict* monotonicity).

Comment: @ClementYung Constant $f$ would lead to constant $T$, but $T$ is given

Comment: @MA I see, you can see my edited answer.

Comment: @ClementYung - Thanks, but I don't think that the $f$ you gave as an example is monotone.